# Problem with submitting URL to index for Ajax crawlable URLs

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-index, ajax

My site contains lots of dynamic data, so I am using Ajax crawling to crawl it properly. When I use the "Fetch as Google" tool in Google Webmaster Tools it's working perfectly, but the "Submit to Google index" button next to the result is not working. It just reloads the page and does nothing.

For [this non-Ajax URL](http://www.getusedparts.com/) it works perfectly and says "URL submitted to index", but not for [this Ajax URL](http://www.getusedparts.com/part/2000/infiniti/i30/#!search).

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Since this has been posted Google has changed the way the index websites and can now even index AJAX pages and the Googlebot sees the page the same as the end user sees it including interactive javascript content and AJAX powered content without needing to make any special changes to your code to suit the Googlebot engine specifically.